# Scroll view only horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have successfully set up a scroll view into my `Main View Controller` so it only scrolls vertically. I then proceeded the same way to set another scroll view in my `Wallet View Controller` but it keeps scrolling horizontally too! I tried every programmatical solution but I could not fix it. The constrains are absolutely the same in both situations which drives me nuts.

Here are a few screenshots of what is going on:

[image: Main View Controller]

[image: Wallet View Controller]

What is the problem?

Comment: Your images are not showing how you're setting up the `.contentSize` of your scroll views... Are you explicitly setting it? Are you using the content's constraints to do it?

Comment: @DonMag I didn't set the `.contentSize` on neither of the `scrollViews`

Comment: If you are trying to set the scrolling nature of a UIScrollView using constraints it also depends on how you constrain the contents so we can't really tell 100% from the images.

Comment: @Martin33000 where you able to solve it?